# sending and receiving logs to aws kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis

How can I send (receive) logs to (from) different kinesis stream shards using python boto3? I can send and receive when there is only one shard but can not figure out how will it work if I specify multiple shards for my kinesis stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kinesis-agent](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent) library to push logs to kinesis streams, and use the [KCL python](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-python) library to read records from the stream. The KCL handles loads of stuff such as reading parallelly from multiple shards, resharding, etc.